# Using PNG/JPG image for pattern fill in actionscript

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, draw

I need to fill shapes (rectangles, ellipses,  etc.) in actionscript with primary patterns like square mesh, slant stripes (monochrome).

What is the most optimal way to do this ?

Should I programmatically generate such patterns ?

Or use bitmap and repeatedly paste them ?

Or is there any other method that I should know of (textures)?

Comment: Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you've tried and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer! Also see [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask)

Comment: Yes, I have posted an answer for this. Earlier I did not know what I was supposed to do at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To achieve this:

1. I embedded the intended source image (PNG/JPG) in a class type variable.

   ```
   public class MyComponent extends UIComponent

   {
     [Embed(source="../assets/FillPattern.png", mimeType="image/png")]
     private var FillImage:Class;
   }
   ```
2. Instantiated the embedded image data.

   ```
   fillBitmap = new FillImage;
   var fillData = fillBitmap.bitmapData;
   ```
3. Used that bitmap data to fill / paint the shape, e.g., a rectangle

   ```
   graphics.beginBitmapFill(fillData, null, true, true);
   graphics.drawRect(0, 0, width, height);
   graphics.endFill();
   ```